# Bootstrap column height and position image at bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, height

```
<section>    
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-8">
             <div class="row">
               <h1>some heading</h1>
               <p>bunch of text that pushes column down</p>
               <h1>some heading</h1>
               <p>bunch of text that pushes column down</p>
               <h1>some heading</h1>
               <p>bunch of text that pushes column down</p>
               <h1>some heading</h1>
               <p>bunch of text that pushes column down</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <!-- this image should align at bottom of the row height -->
              <img src="black_image.jpg">
          </div>
       </row>
    </div>
</section>
<footer> <!-- BG color is same as image above -->
</footer>
```

This has been asked before but I have yet to find a decent answer.  I have tried various hacks found on stack that are supposed to make columns equal the height of the row (xs-container, margin/padding, etc.) and then applying some positioning to the image div  but none of them seem to produce the results I am looking for.

What I am trying to accomplish is making the image look as if its coming out of the footer in the row above so that it sits directly right of the content in col-sm-8 but is aligned at the bottom.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Only way to make equal height columns (both having the height of the tallest one) is tables or css `display: table`. But you don't seem to need that here. You only need to put that img in the `row` and then `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`. With tables you'd need `vertical-align: bottom` on the second column.

Comment: It is not standard CSS (yet) but there is a new tech using flex-boxes. I for one, am looking forward to this! http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Ya tables are not an option.  Kills the responsiveness.  On a phone the image should slide under the content and still appear as if coming out of the footer.

Comment: Agreed Wouter.  Its interesting stuff.  Thanks for the link.  Browser support is lacking though.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 4):

You can try the `col-md-offset-[value]` class.

You can also try this:

```
<footer> 

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 imagefooter">
        <!-- image -->
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Make a custom `style.css` and define the imagefooter and give it a negative top.

Comment: Hmm... this one has some promise.  Let me try it out tonight and get back to you.